# Differentiate between a number (of type double) with decimal places and one without - c++

Tags: c++, integer, double, rounding

I am trying to implement a simple decimation algorithm in c++. I have two arrays, say `p` & `q`, where the subscripts are related to each other by the following relation:

`p[k] = q[0.5*k]`. This means that the following sequence should hold valid:

```
p[0] = q[0]  
p[1] = 0  
p[2] = q[1]  
p[3] = 0  
p[4] = q[2]
```

and so on...

Please note that `p[k]` takes on a value only and only when the result of `(0.5*k)` contains no decimal places (or has 0 in decimal) and does not use any rounding off etc.

**My question is:** Is there a way to distinguish between an integer (a number with no decimal places or only 0 in decimal, say 2.0) and a number with decimal places in C++, provided both are cast to double?

eg.) *2.0 is an integer cast to double. 2.1 is a number with decimal places.*
eg. 2) * 0.9*2 should put 0 into array p while 0.9*10 should put q[9] into array p.*

If I use the statement, `(int) (0.5*k)`, then I end up with an integer in every case, irrespective of the value of k.

**Edit:** The 0.5 in the above case is only illustrative. It could be any number, say 2, 2.5, 0.9, 0.95 etc.)

Any help is most welcome,
Thanks,
Sriram.

Comment: Why not use integer division?

Comment: Also, how do you distinguish between a whole number and an integer in mathematics?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, probably because `4/2` and `5/2` will both return `2`, when `5/2` should instead fail in such a way that Sriram knows to stuff a `0` into `p[5]`.

Comment: Are you arrays made of int ? Couldn't you just use a modulo (%2) and do nothing if the result is different of 0 ?

Comment: What is the difference between whole number and integer?????

Comment: @Johnsyweb: an integer would be something that has decimal places, and a whole number would be a counting number - no decimal places. the jury is still out on what exactly is a whole number though..

Comment: @all: I have edited the question title and the content. I agree that the earlier version of the question was based on my definitions of whole number and integer, which may not be correct. Please feel free to edit and correct my definitions, should the need arise.

Comment: An integer does not have decimal places by definition, only rational or real numbers do.

Comment: @sarnold: yes. that is right. if I could take your statement and extend it to any number (0.5, 0.95 etc.), a solution/pointer to solution to that is what i am looking for.

Comment: 2.5, 0.9, 0.95 are not integers.

Comment: @sriram, is it fair game to pass your `double` array indexes to `ceil(3)` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that the coef can be anything else,

```
p[floor(coef*k)] = (fabs(coef*k-floor(coef*k))<1E-6)?q[k]:0;
```

Comment: if the expression could be changed to compare the result to 1 ( <expr> < 1.0), I think that would be the answer, right? what do you think?

Comment: (coef*k-floor(coef*k)) is the fractional part of coef*k. It would be always <1.

Comment: also except with 0.5 and such, it would be never 0, because of limited precision. That's why I compare with 1E-6 ie 0.000001 - there's no sense to check whether a double _equals_ something.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `k` is of an integer type, you could use `if (k % 2 == 0) ...` to check if `k`is divisible by two:

```
if (k % 2 == 0)
  p[k] = q[k / 2];
else
  p[k] = 0;
```

This can also be expressed using the ternary operator:

```
p[k] = (k % 2 == 0) ? q[k / 2] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The short syntax for what you want to do could be this:

```
p[k] = k % 2 ? 0 : q[k/2];
```

---

> Is there a way to distinguish between a whole number and an integer in C++?

Define whole number, and define integer in this context. I'm confused!

Are you taking about the difference as explained [here?](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-whole-number-and-an-integer.htm)

If you want to detect whether a number is integer or not, then probably this may help:

```
#include<cmath>

bool IsInteger(double d)
{  
    double intpart;
    return std::modf(double number, &intpart) == 0.0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I have edited the question as above. Hope it is more clear

Comment: I may have messed up an earlier version of the question. Please see the edited question and let me know in case you still have questions.

Comment: Your IsInteger function fails badly if `d > LONG_MAX`.  A better solution would be to use `std::modf` (in <cmath>).

Comment: @James: I had this in my mind, but didn't know how to fix that. Anyway, I tried it now with what you suggested. See and let me know if it's correct!

Answer (score 1):

k % 2 is in a couple of answers in this thread.

However, this is not useful in answering the OP's question. Note the edit:
"Edit: The 0.5 in the above case is only illustrative. It could be any number, say 2, 2.5, 0.9, 0.95 etc.)"

k % 2 only works because the value chosen was 0.5. It won't hold true for any other values.

Therefore, unless I'm missing something entirely, the simplest approach I can think of is the following:

Subtract the floor of the number from the number itself. If the result is > 0, it is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have expressions that result in irrational numbers, you could use [Boost.Rational](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/rational/index.html) to represent your indizes.

Answer (score 0):

@Aix's suggestion of `k%2` looks like it'd combine nicely with the `?:` operator:

```
p[k] = (k%2) ? 0 : q[k/2];
```

Comment: ITYM `p[k] = (k % 2) ? 0 : q[k / 2];` ?